# Does the equation of state include all the possible states that a system can exhibit?

Tags: thermodynamics

For a given amount of a chemically defined homogeneous fluid, the equation of state is often represented as $$f(p, V, T) = 0.$$

But, does this include all the possible states that the fluid can be in? For instance, does it also include the state when there is turbulence in the fluid?

Or does the equation of state only show *equilibrium states*?

Also, can we “force” the system to have a $(p, V, T)$ state (possibly momentarily) that doesn’t satisfy its equation of state?

Comment: "Turbulence is fluid motion characterized by chaotic changes in pressure and flow velocity" (Wikipedia). Given that definition, what value of pressure would you use in the equation of state?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equation of state (EOS), being a condition on the state variables $p,V,T$, implies that the macroscopic state of the system is fully characterized by these quantities. The case of a fluid system with a non-zero field of velocities (doesn't matter if turbulent or not) implies that the macrocopic state, in addition to $p,V,T$, would be characterized by the velocity field. So, use of OS is confined to the case of equilibrium states.

In the case of hydrodynamics, it is possible to somewhat extend its use to the case of *local thermodynamic equilibrium*, by assuming that each single fluid element can be described as a thermodynamic system at the local values of the state variables.

Of course, even without a velocity field, it is possible to have a macroscopic, static fluid in a non-equilibrium state. In such a case, the EOS is not obeyed. A simple example is if the variation of $p,V$ and $T$ happens in a time shorter than the slowest relaxation time. A dramatic example of this situation is the case of a super-heated liquid at constant pressure. The equilibrium EOS would predict a low density vapor phase, while it remains in an unstable high density phase.

Comment: What an excellent answer!!!!!!!!!!  It might also be worth mentioning that temperature gradients and concentration gradients also perturb the macroscopic state, as does chemical reaction.  Also, when a phase change occurs, the fractions of the two phases enters as a parameter.